# Image anchor click is not working in IE7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-7

I have below image anchor inside a form. Form id is `myForm`. On click i will call some database call and i have below html code and jquery code.

```
<a id="new"><img src="image.gif"></a>
```

**jQuery code:**

```
$('#myForm #new').click(function() {
    alert("new byutttton clickeddddd");
});
```

But it is not alerting. Am I doing anything wrong here? It works fine in FF.

Comment: is the `new` element actually inside the form? Also, why do you need to select it with both `#myForm` and `#new`? The ID should be unique, so you should only need `#new`. (if it isn't unique, that is a HTML error and may well be the cause of you problem)

Comment: yes new element is inside the form...

Comment: are you doing ajax or something? because it will work the way you have written

Comment: No..am not doing any ajax calls on click of the new

Comment: @user1016403 Which jQuery version you're using, jQuery_2+ don't support IE < 9.

Comment: I am using jquery-1.4.1.min.js

Comment: @user1016403 Then your code should should work as it is. You really don't need `href`, if you want an anchor. Have you checked `#new` exists when you attach the eventlistener? You could try to attach it in `window.onload` instead of `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: not using href breaks native functionality in plenty of user agents. include href. if it goes nowhere, href="#nogo"

Answer (score 0):

IE7 most likely required an href attribute on the element. You may want to use a different element other than an anchor for this functionality. you also only need one ID for the selector as they should be unique.

Try

```
<a id="new" href="#"><img src="image.gif"></a> 

$('#new').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("new byutttton clickeddddd");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`"<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="new"><img src="image.gif"></a>`"

I think you are missing href tag use like this

Answer (score 0):

I would switch to the 'on' jQuery event

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="new"><img src="/" alt="my image" /></a>
```

jQuery

```
$("#new").on("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("new byutttton clickeddddd");
});
```

Remove #myForm. You are overqualifying the selector as well. But that's not a big deal I suppose.

Comment: Also, do i need to use href attribute?

Comment: Yes, include the <a href="#" id="new">...</a>

Comment: Please check out this jsfiddle and let me know if it works for you in IE7. This is bare minimum to correctly function: http://jsfiddle.net/Nejhw/

Comment: @kunalbhat and all other answerers, obviously OP wants an anchor, not a link. Btw, afaik jsFiddle has dropped support for IE < 9.

Comment: jsfiddle link itself is not opening for me in IE7. it has a script error saying 'editor' is null or not an object.